# I have two PCBs in kicad that will be connected using a soldered flat 10 way cable, how can I make kicad think they are connected?

Tags: kicad

I have the two pcbs side by side but now have disconnections in the rats nest. Is there a way to tell kicad that these will be connected in the future without having to draw wires connecting them ? Is there a special symbol or something ?

Comment: Normally, EDA tools like KiCad are there do describe circuits _strictly at the board level_, and you neither need to nor want to use it to show board interconnect.  What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I have processor and comms board and then another board with sensors on it. The sensors are at different pressures (it measured pressure difference, mainly), So I am going to use a ribbon cable to connect them inside the instrument housing. They ae so closely related that I wanted them on the same kicad schematic

Comment: _I'm trying to talk you out of doing something you'll regret_.  If you must do it, add a layer to the board for your board interconnect, and run your signals there.  A Gerber plot will be generated for it -- when you submit your board set to the board house, just leave that file out.

Comment: @TimWescott   sounds like you might be saying its better to break this into two kicad instances, a proc/comms board and a sensor board ?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what I'm recommending.

Comment: Normally in a professional environment you'd have a separate design for each board, then a drawing showing the interconnect.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice. I think that counts as an answer!

Comment: What you could do is to name the nets so that they are e.g XXX_A at one connector and XXX_B at second connector. Then programs do not know they are connected, but you can put the connectors right next to each other  so you can wire the A nets to one connector and B nets to the other. I don't understand why I did not put this as answer. I can move it as an answer if this is good, but this is a borderline kludge solution to a thing that's usually not done.

Comment: is each of the connectors near the edge of the board? ... could the two boards be designed as one board that is cut into two after assembly?